# Syntax error before '^' token

Tags: iphone, c, objective-c, xcode, core-plot

I just upgraded core-plot to the latest version in an application that was already running successful plots. I followed the fairly simple instructions to the letter, however I'm getting 20 syntax errors in UIView.h. [It seems that I'm not alone](http://groups.google.com/group/coreplot-discuss/browse_thread/thread/a29b0076c8e646b0/9d337d3d799129b0?lnk=gst&q=syntax+error#9d337d3d799129b0), but nobody has of yet posted a solution to the issue.

An example:

This code from UIView.h

```
+ (void)animateWithDuration:(NSTimeInterval)duration delay:(NSTimeInterval)delay options:(UIViewAnimationOptions)options animations:(void (^)(void))animations completion:(void (^)(BOOL finished))completion __OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTING(__MAC_NA,__IPHONE_4_0);
```

gives the compile error "Syntax error before '^' token":

```
/var/folders/UO/UOZJs7XuF5iROp2HMSTlz++++TI/-Caches-/com.apple.Xcode.501/CompositeSDKs/iphonesimulator-iPhoneSimulator4.0-drysryiarqddqccmfooifrjfbivi/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIView.h:250:0 Syntax error before '^' token in /var/folders/UO/UOZJs7XuF5iROp2HMSTlz++++TI/-Caches-/com.apple.Xcode.501/CompositeSDKs/iphonesimulator-iPhoneSimulator4.0-drysryiarqddqccmfooifrjfbivi/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIView.h
```

It believe the solution is related to the build settings. What would cause this error? I'm not familiar with the (^) syntax in Objective-C.

Comment: Since Core Plot is a work-in-progress, this is probably best addressed on the core-plot issue tracker (http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/issues/list) or mailing list (coreplot-discuss@googlegroups.com). As it is, the question will only be relevant until the issue is fixed in the Core Plot sources.

Comment: As the answer you cite from the coreplot-discuss list suggests, you (or the original poster) appear to be trying to do something unsuported (compile as an SDK). It's no surprise it doesn't work out of the box nor that anyone has stepped forward to fix it beyond suggesting where you might start to look if you wanted to fix it yourself.

Comment: The core-plot owner doesn't appear to know the answer, but I would think one of the C gurus on SO would have seen something similar before.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `^` in that context is Apple's implementation of [blocks](http://developer.apple.com/mac/articles/cocoa/introblocksgcd.html).

My first guess is that you're trying to compile the library with GCC 4.0, which does not recognize the syntax.  Perhaps try changing your compiler settings to GCC (or LLVM-GCC) 4.2.

Another compiler-related option that may help is to change the compiler away from GCC entirely.  If Clang also has trouble with the compilation, chances are it will show you a better error message.

Comment: Yes! It was using GCC 4.0. Changing to GCC 4.2 fixed the problem.

Comment: I had the exact same issue. The compiler was set to GCC 4.2 in my case. Changing it to LLVM-GCC 4.2 fixed the issue.